# Arbitrary probability dice

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I have to make this: Each set consists of a number of equal objects that generate numbers from a finite set with an arbitrary probability distribution. I did make it, but it feels so long. How can I refactor the code to something better and clean looking? Also, don't mind certain variable names and callbacks. I've done it for satire purposes

```
#Assignment
import time
import random
def roll(die):
    number = random.randint(0,len(die)-1)
    b = die[number]
    return b

Die1 = [1,2,3,4]
Die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #num lists
def inptchacc(string):
    ending_conditions = ['stop','Stop','quit','Quit']
    end = False
    inpu = input(string)
    while end == False:
        if not(inpu in ending_conditions):
            try:
                retr = int(inpu)
                return retr
            except:
                string = 'invalid input please try again'
                inpu = input('invalid input please try again ')
        else:
            stop = 'stop'
            return stop

def quantitymatrix(IDie):
    stringDie = 'how often would you like this Die to occur?'
    list = []
    Adding = True
    while Adding:
        print('the Die in question is '+ str(IDie))
        toadd = inptchacc(string)
        if toadd != 'stop':
            list.append(toadd)
        else:
            Adding = False
    return list

def deeper(IDie):
    stringDie = 'what number would you like to add to the new face of the Die? (to end the die please type "stop or Stop or quit or Quit to finish the DIE" )'
    list = []
    Adding = True
    while Adding:
        print('The Die ' + IDie + ' is currently ' + str(list) )
        toadd = inptchacc(stringDie)
        if toadd != 'stop':
            list.append(toadd)
        else:
            Adding = False
    return list

def chance_overlap(dielist,Dielistcount):
    highnumber = 100000
    counter = (len(dielist))*[0]
    chance = (len(dielist))*[0]
    for n in range(highnumber):
        dieres = len(Dielistcount)*[0]
        for dienumber in range(len(dielist)):
            for diecount in range(Dielistcount[dienumber]):
                dieres[dienumber] += roll(dielist[dienumber])
        for dienumber2 in range(len(dielist)):
            if max(dieres) == dieres[dienumber2] and dieres.count(max(dieres)) == 1:
                counter[dienumber2] += 1
    for chanceper in range(len(counter)):
        chance[chanceper] = counter[chanceper]/highnumber
        chance[chanceper] = str(chance[chanceper]) + '% for die' + str(chanceper+1)
    return chance

def suckmypp(counterq):
    string1 = 'adding the amount of the die '+ str(counterq+1)
    firstq = True
    while firstq:
        suckmypp2 = inptchacc(string1)
        if suckmypp2 != 'stop':
            firstq = False
    return suckmypp2

Dielist1 = [Die1,Die2]
diecount = [9,6]
chance = chance_overlap(Dielist1,diecount)

print(chance)
Doing = True
counter = 0

while Doing:

        Dielist2 = []
        adding = True
        while adding:

            counter += 1
            addQ = input('to stop type S and enter otherwise any characters and enter will add another die')
            if addQ != 'S':
                notdone = True
                while notdone:
                    dietoadd = deeper('Die' + str(counter))
                    if len(dietoadd) >= 1:
                        Dielist2.append(dietoadd)
                        notdone = False
                    else:
                        print('die is empty not added')
            else:
                adding = False
        quantity = True
        counterq = 0
        Qlist = []
        print(Qlist)
        print(len(Dielist2))
        while quantity:
            Qlist.append(suckmypp(counterq))
            counterq += 1
            if counterq == (len(Dielist2)):
                quantity = False

        print(Dielist2)
        print(Qlist)
        chance2 = chance_overlap(Dielist2,Qlist)
        Doing = False


print(chance2)
```

Comment: Is there any reason one of the function names is `suckmypp`, which happpens to return `suckmypp2`?

Answer (score 3):

### roll()

- Your `roll` function implements [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice), so its definition can be replaced with

  ```
  from random import choice as roll
  ```

### inptchacc()

- Instead of having several words for upper-case/lower-case letters, it is more convenient to declare only lower-case versions and convert input to lower-case before comparing. Also, using operator `not in` is more readable than `not ... in ...`:

  ```
  stop_words = ['stop', 'quit']
  if inpu.lower() not in stop_words:
      # ...
  ```
- You do not need variable `end`; remove it and use a `while True` loop.
- You can place `inpu = input()` at the beginning of the `while` loop to avoid its duplication.
- You do not need to store value into a variable before returning it; just return an expression.
- Using a [guard clause](https://medium.com/softframe/what-are-guard-clauses-and-how-to-use-them-350c8f1b6fd2) for checking stop condition will reduce nesting.
- Renaming `string` to `prompt` looks appropriate. Also, try to avoid ugly names like `inpu`. Use `input_` or `value` instead.

  > If your public attribute name collides with a reserved keyword, append a single trailing underscore to your attribute name. This is preferable to an abbreviation or corrupted spelling.  ([PEP-8](https://pep8.org))

```
def inptchacc(string):
    while True:
        inpu = input(string)
        if inpu in ['stop','quit']:
            return 'stop'
        try:
            return int(inpu)
        except:
            string = 'invalid input please try again'
```

### quantitymatrix() and deeper()

- `quantitymatrix()` is unused.
- According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

  > Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
  >   Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
- You do not need the variable `Adding`, just use `whilte True` and replace `Adding = False` with `break`
- It is bad practice to override builtin functions (`list`), better use `list_` or `lst`. Actually, here name `die` is more appropriate since this list represents a die!
- Use `print()` with several arguments instead of converting `list` to `str`.

```
def deeper(idie):
    die = []
    while True:
        print('The Die ' + idie + ' is currently', die)
        to_add = inptchacc(
                'what number would you like to add to the new face '
                'of the Die? (to end the die type "stop" or "quit")'
                )
        if to_add == 'stop':
            break
        die.append(to_add)
    return die
```

### chance_overlap()

- Use `_` or `__` name for unused variables (`n`, `diecount`).
- `dieres` evaluation may be done like this:

  ```
  dieres = [
      sum(roll(die) for __ in range(repeat))
      for (die, repeat) in zip(die_list, die_list_count)
  ]
  ```
- When updating `counter` it is more efficient to check if there is a winner outside of the `for` loop. Actually, you do not need the `for` loop at all:

  ```
  maximum = max(dieres)
  if dieres.count(maximum) == 1:
      winner = dieres.index(maximum)
      counter[winner] += 1
  ```
- You do not need the `chance` list; just replace last loop with list comprehension:

  ```
  return [
      str(count / highnumber) + '% for die' + str(i)
      for (i, count) in enumerate(counter, start=1)
  ]
  ```

So the final version of `chance_overlap()` is:

```
def chance_overlap(die_list, die_list_count):
    high_number = 100000
    counter = len(die_list) * [0]
    for __ in range(high_number):
        dieres = [
            sum(roll(die) for __ in range(repeat))
            for (die, repeat) in zip(die_list, die_list_count)
        ]

        maximum = max(dieres)
        if dieres.count(maximum) == 1:
            winner = dieres.index(maximum)
            counter[winner] += 1

    return [
        str(count / high_number) + '% for die' + str(i)
        for (i, count) in enumerate(counter, start=1)
    ]
```

### main

- `while Doing` is redundant: `Doing` is just set to `False` at the end of loop :/
- `if len(dietoadd) >= 1` should be replaced with `if dietoadd`. Actually, it is better to move this check inside `deeper` ("read die" function), so `die_list_2` could be read much simpler:

  ```
  die_list_2 = []
  while input('to stop enter S') != 'S':
      die_list_2.append(deeper('Die' + str(len(die_list_2))))
  ```
- `while quantity` loop may be removed because you can construct `Qlist` in a single line:

  ```
  Qlist = [suckmypp(counterq) for counterq in range(len(die_list_2))]
  ```
- inline variables that are used only once, e. g. `chance` and `chance2` could be removed if you call `chance_overlap` inside `print()`.

So, after all refactoring main part should look like:

```
die_list_1 = [Die1, Die2]
diecount = [9, 6]
print(chance_overlap(die_list_1, diecount))

die_list_2 = []
while input('to stop enter "S"') != 'S':
    die_list_2.append(deeper('Die' + str(len(die_list_2))))

q_list = [suckmypp(counterq) for counterq in range(len(die_list_2))]

print(die_list_2)
print(q_list)
print(chance_overlap(die_list_2, q_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been brave enough to read through all the code. If your variables and function are to have irrelevant names, then I'd highly recommend commenting your code so that people will be more willing to read it.

I have however noticed one thing : the function `roll` can be    replaced by the use of `randrange(die) + 1`, and therefore the variables    `Die1` and `Die2` need only be an integer, representing the maximum    value of the die.

Also, if you create lists -like Die1 and Die2 here-,    think about    using range() and **list comprehensions** : `Die1 = [x+1 for x in range(4)]`. If you want to cast a d100, it'll be easier than hardcoding each number yourself    (would still go with `random.randrange(100) + 1`, though)

Here's the documentation for the `randrange` function in the `random` module : https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange